# Ansible: print only user defined variables

Tags: ansible

How can I print variables declared only at `group_vars`, `host_vars` without ansible facts?

such code is good:

```
- name: "Ansible | List all known variables and facts"
  debug:
    var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```

But I don't need host IPs,disks, etc.

I mean to check all my variables one more time before continue to execute Play.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 categories of variables: [ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts), [special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables), and user's variables. Remove both ansible facts and special variables from hostvars and what is left are user's variables. The list of the ansible facts is available in the variables *ansible_facts*. The list of the special variables must be created (I think).

**Create a list of special variables**

If you run the playbook below you'll see the list of the special variables and user's variables

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]|
                 difference(ansible_facts) }}"
```

Eliminate the user's vars and put the list of the special variables into a file. For example

```yaml
shell> cat special_vars.yml
special_vars:
  - ansible_python_interpreter
  - ansible_connection
  - inventory_hostname
    ...
```

This list of special variables might be not complete and will serve the purpose of this host only.

**Remove ansible facts and special variables from hostvars**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - special_vars.yml
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        user_var1: AAA
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]|
                 difference(ansible_facts)
                 difference(special_vars) }}"
```

gives the list of user's variables only

```yaml
  msg:
  - user_var1
```

The user's variables will include also the configuration variables set by the user (e.g. [connection variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#connection-variables): ansible_user or [priviledge escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/become.html#become-privilege-escalation): ansible_become).

---

**Name-space**

A better practice is to "name-space" variables. For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    prj51_var1: AAA
    prj51_var2: BBB
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}: {{ query('vars', item)|first }}"
      loop: "{{ query('varnames', 'prj51_.+$') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 'prj51_var1: AAA'
  msg: 'prj51_var2: BBB'
```